# vb.net when i build it is showing 0 errors but when i execute it is raising this error

Tags: vb.net

The type for variable 'cri' will not be inferred because it is bound to a field in an enclosing scope. Either change the name of 'cri', of use the fully qualified name (for example, 'Me.cri' or 'MyBase.cri')

I have created a class file with name Predefined which consists of this methods like cricket,BasketBall from this methos im returning List of string type

im calling that class in button click event like the object of class is pre
now im calling a method called pre.Cricket();
so when i execute the program with warnings it is raising this error:

```
'Cricket' is not a member of 'predefined'.
```

this is the code where it is showing error in line 2:

```
Dim cric As New List(Of String)()
cric = pre.Cricket()
For cri As Integer = 0 To cric.Count - 1
```

Comment: please show us some code. Also, did you try placing a break point on the line that's throwing the error? Do you have a stack trace? Much Much more info needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this msdn article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385162.aspx

(from above)

> A loop control variable in your code
>   has the same name as a field of the
>   class or other enclosing scope.
>   Because the control variable is used
>   without an As clause, it is bound to
>   the field in the enclosing scope, and
>   the compiler does not create a new
>   variable for it or infer its type.
>
> In the following example, Index, the
>   control variable in the For statement,
>   is bound to the Index field in the
>   Customer class. The compiler does not
>   create a new variable for the control
>   variable Index or infer its type.

```
Class Customer

    ' The class has a field named Index.
    Private Index As Integer

    Sub Main()

    ' The following line will raise this warning.
        For Index = 1 To 10
            ' ...
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```